# How to run my container as a nonRoot user

Tags: docker

My dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
RUN useradd -u 8877 john
USER john
```

```
// docker build -t my-apache2 .

// docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add specific user then solution is to create a custom image which extends a base image and adds a user e.g.

```
FROM:httpd
USER <user>[:<group>]
```

and then you can run container with that user

```
docker run --user <user>[:<group>] httpd
```

Without extending the base image you will receive the following error message from docker engine

```
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user <user>: no matching entries in passwd file
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

If you want to use the stock image with non-root user then instead of using a username above you can just specify its UID instead. This will make linux run as that user id without having to check if it exists or not.

Of course, any files that it interacts with will need to be writable by that user. But as an example, change the default user and group within a container to your own with adding `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`:

```
docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 --user $(id -u):$(id -g) my-apache2
```

See the docker command line reference here
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: Can i do it inside my dockerfile?  and then run docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2

Comment: as you have already mentioned `USER john` in your last line of dockerfile. You can now run it with a `--user` flag e.g. 
 `docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 --user john my-apache2`